# Java Messenger service topic subscriber program termination

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, producer-consumer

I have a JMS ( ACTIVEMQ ) subscriber(asynchronous) that is polling a topic to receive the message from the JMS provider. The provider is putting an object message into the topic every 5 sec and that subscriber is receiving it as usual.Now when the subscriber terminates, the publisher still continuous to put the messages into the topic. so i want to know how can i handle the program termination of subscriber( i,e i want to know how to handle or what method is called when the subscriber terminates). when the subscriber shuts , the provider keeps on putting the messages into the topic . The provider is running on the server and subscriber is running on the client.
please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Advisory Messages is probably what you are looking for. I have not implemented them myself, but I've read it is possible. You should be looking at the **consumerCount**

Cheers, Eugene.